# Visitor IP information - WP Google Maps Plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

We understand that the WP Google Maps plugin does not directly share any information with Google, however, the plugin does make use of the Google Maps API and in doing so, for certain features such as Geolocation as an example, the Google Maps API requires a users IP information in order to make use of the Geolocation features.

Can someone let us know if Google shares the visitor information (particularly Visitor IP information)?

Here is our flow -

1. We are using market cluster in map
2. Map has been linked into custom post type “Case studies”
3. All the Post’s locations categorized under marker categories
4. We are using search by keywords and search filter by categories
5. Info window has been customized to display a few custom fields in the window

Comment: You should assume that Google gathers, uses, and possibly sells every bit of data your users send them from their browsers and every bit your server sends them. That is their business. Take a look at Open Street Maps as an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

From the [terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/termshttps://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms).

*4.4 Data Use, Protection, and Privacy.*

*4.4.1 Data Use and Retention. To provide the Services through the Customer Application(s), Google collects and receives data from Customer and End Users (and End Users’ End Users, if any), including search terms, IP addresses, and latitude/longitude coordinates. Customer acknowledges and agrees that Google and its Affiliates may use and retain this data to provide and improve Google products and services, subject to the Google Privacy Policy at https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/.*

*4.4.2 European Data Protection Terms. Google and Customer agree to the Google Maps Controller-Controller Data Protection Terms at https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-controller-terms.
4.4.3 End User Requirements.*

*(a) End User Privacy.  Customer’s use of the Services in the Customer Application will comply with applicable privacy laws, including laws regarding Services that store and access Cookies on End Users’ devices.   Customer will comply with the then-current Consent Policy at https://www.google.com/about/company/user-consent-policy.html, if applicable.
(b) End User Personal Data. Through the normal functioning of the Google Maps Core Services, End Users provide personally identifiable information and Personal Data directly to Google, subject to the then-current Google Privacy Policy at https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/. (a) However, Customer will not provide to Google (i) any End User’s personally identifiable information; or (ii) any European End User’s Personal Data (where “European” means “European Economic Area, Switzerland, or the UK”).
(c) End User Location Privacy Requirements. To safeguard End Users’ location privacy, Customer will ensure that the Customer Application(s): (i) notify End Users in advance of (1) the type(s) of data that Customer intends to collect from the End Users or the End Users’ devices, and (2) the combination and use of End User's location with any other data provider's data; and (ii) will not obtain or cache any End User's location except with the End User's express, prior, revocable consent.*

Comment: Thank you. This helps. We have a follow-up question on a particular API.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312757/google-maps-javascript-api-wp-plugin

Comment: For any additional questions, we would suggest creating a support case in the Google Cloud Console to open a personalized communication channel: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case